# How to add extra path to uri in spring cloud gatway

Tags: java, spring, cloud, gateway

I want to add custom path for different apis in spring cloud gateway.

I have two apis:

1. Service1: `http://localhost:2121`

service 1 has endpoint like: `http://localhost:2121/abc`

2. Service2: `http://localhost:3434`

service 2 has endpoint like `http://localhost:3434/abc`

api gateway: `http://localhost:8090`

Problem:

I would like to add service1 path to API Gateway and I want to redirect to service 1

example 1: `http://localhost:8090/service1/abc` should redirect to `http://localhost:2121/abc`

example 2: `http://localhost:8090/service1/anything` should redirect to `http://localhost:2121/anything`

same things for service 2.

I use yml configuration for spring cloud gateway.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: service1
          uri: http://localhost:2121
        - id: service2
          uri: http://localhost:3434
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spring:
    cloud:
        gateway:
            routes:
            -  id: service1
               uri: http://localhost:2121
               predicates:
               -   Path=/service1/**
               filters:
               -   StripPrefix=1
            -  id: service2
               uri: http://localhost:3434
               predicates:
               -   Path=/service2/**
               filters:
               -   StripPrefix=1
```

then all requests mapping '/service1/xxxx' will proxy to service_1 '/xxxx'.

[spring cloud gateway reference](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/) will give you more details.